# Region of convergence of complex series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$.

Tags: complex-numbers

How to find region of convergence of complex series $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{z+n}$? According to me if z is any complex number then series is just like real alternating series so by Abel’s test of alternating series it is convergent . So according to me it’s is convergent in entire complex plane . Please suggest me exact reason . Thanks .

Comment: Is $n$ the usual 1, 2, 3, ... to infinity ?

Comment: Yes as usual ...

Answer (score 1):

Couple together adjacent terms:
$$-\frac1{z+2m-1}+\frac1{z+2m}=-\frac1{(z+2m-1)(z+2m)}.$$
We get a new series that converges absolutely, everywhere, save of
course where the denominators vanish.